# Matlab : extract set of negative and positive values from a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Good Afternoon;

i have a matrix A 129 by 81 and what i have to do is to look for negative and positive values. There are no nul values. The problem is that i have to create a loop which goes toward rows and columns and look for positive or negative vals but once it moves from negative to positive or vice-versa , the range of those (e.g negative) values have to be stored in a matrix and then it moves to positive values and store it . I don't know if there is a smart function or tool to do this ...Need some help if you want me to explain more , no problem with it ...

Thanks

Adam[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuit5.jpg)

Comment: Can you add an example, your question is not clear.

Comment: so it's the figure called okubo weiss and what i have to do it's to track structures with negative and with positive values and then calculate their radius

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if your looking to "separate" the matrix based on the sign of its entry, there is a quite easy way:

In MATLAB, a useful function (but quite expensive computational-wise) is `find`. This will give you the entries of your matrix (or vector) that satisfy the condition:
Say your matrix is `A`.

`positiveIndices = find(A > 0)`

will give you the index where `A` is positive. Then `A(positiveIndices)` will return all of your negative elements of `A`. You can always take a look at the documentation